# 301 redirect help after changing Wordpress permalinks from postname to post_id

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have searched here, wordpress.org and the wider internet, but all the information I can find is the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.

I have taken over maintenance of a large 10-year old Wordpress site (v.4.5.3) with about 3,000 posts, nearly 100 pages and some 5,000 unique hits per day, and now we want to change the permalink structure because the old one is no longer appropriate.

The present permalink structure is /%category%/%postname%.html

We want to change it to simply /%post_id%

As a second choice, reverting to the default /?p=123 format would also be acceptable.

The problem is, how do I manage the 301 redirects for this in .htaccess?  I don't want to use a plugin if I can help it, I'd rather do it manually.

My .htaccess is presently as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Add this rule to your htaccess RewriteRule ^%category%/%postname%\.html$ /%post_id%? [L,R=301] and then check

Comment: Thank you.  I've just tried that on my test site but it isn't redirecting.  Have I added it to the right place?  Do I need to change anything else?  I have checked that the .htaccess has been modified on the server and internal links are working fine.  My .htaccess now looks like this: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^%category%/%postname%\.html$ /%post_id%? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`